# html to pdf using jsPdf is not working with react app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jspdf

I am using react as a frontend application, I want to export a portion of react component as pdf file using jsPdf.

```
const handleDownload = () => {
  const content = document.getElementById('download-content');
  const doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.html(content);
  doc.save("a4.pdf");
}
```

React return component is:

```
return (
<body>
  <header id='download-content'>
    <div>l kldfjlkasjfld asjflkajf ljfasd'flksdasjf lsdasjfsadf</div>
    <div>l kldfjlkasjfld asjflkajf ljfasd'flksdasjf lsdasjfsadf</div>
    <div>l kldfjlkasjfld asjflkajf ljfasd'flksdasjf lsdasjfsadf</div>
    <div>l kldfjlkasjfld asjflkajf ljfasd'flksdasjf lsdasjfsadf</div>
    <div>l kldfjlkasjfld asjflkajf ljfasd'flksdasjf lsdasjfsadf</div>
    <div>l kldfjlkasjfld asjflkajf ljfasd'flksdasjf lsdasjfsadf</div>
  </header>
  <footer>
    <button onClick={handleDownload}>Download</button>
  </footer>
</body>
)
```

After click on `Download` button I want a pdf file which consists `header` tag data with style. But here I got blank pdf with this function `handleDownload`.

I don't want to use canvas to generate image and then make pdf.. If I use canvas then, when page size minimize the pdf will change.

How can I get exact html generated page as pdf?

Answer (score 6):

2 Things:

1. When getting access to a DOM Element in react you should always use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)
2. It appears that [.html](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html) method is async and requires a callback

A working example would be something like this:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';

export default function PDF() {
    const pdfRef = useRef(null);

    const handleDownload = () => {
        const content = pdfRef.current;

        const doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.html(content, {
            callback: function (doc) {
                doc.save('sample.pdf');
            }
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <header ref={pdfRef}>
                <div>l kldfjlkasjfld asjflkajf ljfasd'flksdasjf lsdasjfsadf</div>
                <div>l kldfjlkasjfld asjflkajf ljfasd'flksdasjf lsdasjfsadf</div>
                <div>l kldfjlkasjfld asjflkajf ljfasd'flksdasjf lsdasjfsadf</div>
                <div>l kldfjlkasjfld asjflkajf ljfasd'flksdasjf lsdasjfsadf</div>
                <div>l kldfjlkasjfld asjflkajf ljfasd'flksdasjf lsdasjfsadf</div>
                <div>l kldfjlkasjfld asjflkajf ljfasd'flksdasjf lsdasjfsadf</div>
            </header>
            <footer>
                <button onClick={handleDownload}>Download</button>
            </footer>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Update**

If you need to control the size you can add additional properties as per documentation cited above:

Option 1 - use the `html2canvas` option and control the scale:

```
const handleDownload = () => {
    const content = pdfRef.current;

    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.html(content, {
        callback: function (doc) {
            doc.save('sample.pdf');
        },
        html2canvas: { scale: 0.5 } // change the scale to whatever number you need
    });
};
```

Option 2 - use `width` and `windowWidth`:

```
const handleDownload = () => {
    const content = pdfRef.current;

    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.html(content, {
        callback: function (doc) {
            doc.save('sample.pdf');
        },
        width: 200, // <- here
        windowWidth: 200 // <- here
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. But the full `div` tag not show. It's cuttoff half content. How can I got properly all things. 
Also, when I do responsive the content got in pdf not remain same. It also become like response.. but I want it as standard as full page view

Comment: You can add `width` and `windowWidth` as per the documentation based on your needs. See updated answer

Comment: @JhonArab Basically you need to look at all the options the lib provides and figure out how to use it for your needs...

Comment: thank you so much. You are superb.

Comment: hey @SakoBu, what do I do if I want to add a page to the document, inside this callback? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
// use can you ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element) 

import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
export const dow = () => {
  let htmlElement = <div>Hello </div> 
  let elementAsString = renderToString(htmlElement);
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.html(elementAsString, {
    callback: function (doc) {
      doc.save("test.pdf");
    },
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
  });
};

// use can use this code as function to handle an event
```

Answer (score 0):

**If I understood your question correctly**

*Here is my approach to your question:*

```
 const handleDownload = ()=>{
//content retrieves the element.
let content  = document.getElementById("download-content")
/*
 content2 retrieves the HTML code using ".outerHTML" as a string , 
 then add a line break between two opening tags, 
 as well as a line break between a closing tag and an opening tag 
 with the use of .replace and regexp
 */
let content2 = content.outerHTML.replace(/<(\w+)>(.*?)/g, '\n<$1>\n$2').replace(/(<\/\w+>)/g, '\n$1\n')
var doc = new jsPDF()
// This allows adding text to a PDF. 
doc.text(content2, 10 , 10)
doc.save("a4.pdf")
```

}

***I hope this response meets your needs.***